# Whats wrong with my template function, its giving me the error of no known conversion?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, comparator

So here is my template, which has a `findMax` function in order to find the largest rectangle object in a vector:

```cpp
template<typename Object, typename Comparator> 
const Object & findMax(const std::vector<Object> & rectangles, 
Comparator cmp) { 
   int MAX = 0; 
 
   for(int i = 1; i < rectangles.size(); i++) { 
      if(cmp(rectangles[MAX], rectangles[i])) { 
         MAX = i; 
      } 
   } 
   return rectangles[MAX]; 
}
```

and here is the the line of code where the error occurs:

```cpp
rectangleVec[findMax(rectangleVec,CompareArea::isLessThan)].display();
```

My display function works, and now I'm simply trying to display the rectangle is finds largest, but I get the error:

> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const Rectangle' to 'std::vector::size_type

I'm stumped, what should I try?

Comment: `vector::operator[]` is not able to consume `const Rectangle` that your function returns. It expects an unsigned number.

Comment: Did you mean to return `MAX` instead of `rectangles[MAX]`? Or replace `rectangleVec[findMax(rectangleVec,CompareArea::isLessThan)].display()` with `findMax(rectangleVec,CompareArea::isLessThan).display()`

Comment: minor unrelated issue - if you pass in an empty vector for rectangle, it it will throw an unexpected exception since `rectangles[0]` is an invalid access.

Comment: @selbie It might, or it might not. `rectangles[0]` when `rectangles.size() == 0` is undefined behavior. It might throw an unexpected exception, or something else entirely might happen.

Comment: Check your full error message for an indication of which character in that line of code is identified as the location of the error. Especially with compound expressions, the character position is on par with the line position in terms of importance. If the character is the "f" in "findMax", that tells you that the "from" ('const Rectangle') is the return value of `findMax` and the "to" ('std::vector::size_type') is what you are trying to do with the return value (use as an index into `rectangleVec`).

Comment: Compound expressions can make debugging more confusing. So when you encounter a syntax error on a line with a compound expression, you might want to break it up. Comment out the line of code where the error occurs (so you can easily restore it later), and add in the code broken into smaller pieces, as in `auto& found = findMax(rectangleVec,CompareArea::isLessThan);` and `rectangleVec[found].display();`. Now where does the error occur?